# Spread operator causing "Attempted import error" in `npm run build`, but development mode compiles fine

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-redux, create-react-app

I'm receiving the following error after running `npm build run` which goes away after removing the line with the spread operator:

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/Footer.js
Attempted import error: 'getText' is not exported from './Getters'.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-redux-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-redux-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additi
onal logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myName/.npm/_logs/2020-08-24T22_14_07_926Z-deb
ug.log
```

1. App.js (main app cleaned up from `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux`)
2. Footer.js (Component)
3. Getters.js (selector file)

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Footer from './Footer';
import { getText } from './Getters';

function App() {
  return <Footer/>
}

export default App;
```

**Footer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getText } from './Getters'; 

function Footer(){

  let text = useSelector( state => 
    getText( state, 'menuName' )
  )

  return <h1>{text}</h1>;

}

export default Footer;
```

**Getters.js**

```
let Getters = {}

Getters.thisFunctionIsCausingTrouble = function( state, tableName ){

  let toRet = { ...state };
  return toRet;
}

Getters.getText = function( state ){
  return 'Text';
}

module.exports = Getters;
```

Everything works perfectly fine on localhost, but when I try to build it just screws up.

Again, when I remove the spread operator of the other function, it builds fine.

Another strange result is that if I remove the `import Footer` and Footer call from the app then I get a successful build. (The `getText` import remains in `App.js`).

Why the build fail?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-redux-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the export from es6 to .jsx. module.exports is a es6 version of exporting. I had similar problem. Fixed it by adding export in front of the function name. ex: export const getheader = () => {...}

then You should be able to import it the way you currently are.

Comment: module.exports is CommonJS not ES6

Your suggestion of switching to ESM syntax and a named export is totally on point though!